# Did Zero-Two regain her memories far earlier? [spoiler alert]

Tags: darling-in-the-franxx

I'm doing currently a quick rewatch in order to find out hidden details, symbolism etc..

I noticed a possibility that Zero-Two could regain her memories far earlier than Hiiro. Even before visiting "Garden".

It would be even possible that she regained the memories, but didn't recognize him as him just after first meeting, or could have doubts if he is really he for long time or still could be afraid of rejection for being a demon.

Following this way of thinking, she could even believe that her "old darling" died in a battle long time ago like other yearlings and the person she met recently is only a clone. (Just as former 13th squad or Nana)

Obviously she seems like she does not recognize him during their first meeting (in recent timeline) but it seems like it might happen after about 1st-2nd episode.

**Could you please help me find some references to similar investigation?**

Or maybe I will try to state my question directly: **Did she regain her memories before Hiiro? If yes, when approximately?**

Comment: Hi, looks like this is a ["Is my theory right?"](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014/2516) question. Considering this is a Q&A site and extended discussion is discouraged, I'd recommend splitting the post as: a question asking the core issue itself, and a self-answer with your hypothesis (because your hypothesis *is* one of the answers). That way, future answerers can answer the question independently of your theory, and your theory can still be evaluated accordingly by the community. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @AkiTanaka, I didn't see this guideline before. It helped improve my question significantly (but how to split it wasn't obvious at the first glance)

Answer (score 5):

When Zero Two first met Hiro, she didn't recognize him, and was using him as a fodder to help her find her "real darling", but she didn't know that hiro was her real darling.

Then, later on, during a battle, Zero Two realized that Hiro is her darling. But she doesn't remember the memory when they were little, she just remembered that Hiro is her darling.

Answer (score 2):

What I have found already:

**Evidence:**

- During their childhood escape, Hiro treats Zero Two with candies. He says "Aaa-mu" so that she would open her mouth. Later on, during breakfast in the early episodes, she does exactly the same with Hiro.
- She uses the word "darling" and refers to herself as Zero Two instead of her code name, 002, or her special forces name, 9'℩. These were concepts originally brought about to her by Hiro, and  should (especially her nickname) have been removed by the memory erasure.
- She seems to believe that Hiro is the only one that can "turn on" the rain. It is because during their childhood trip, he used to be smarter and more diligent and taught her many things.
- She promises to take him away from the plantation with her, as he rescued her from the laboratory (perhaps some form of returning the favour).

**Counter arguments:**

- Her way of acting could be some form of "muscle memory" or concepts deeply embedded into her psyche in order to help her psychology console herself during stressful situations.
- Her memory erasure was only performed semi-successfully. It may not have affected, for instance, any words that she had learned.